# Python: first element in a nested list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I would like a list that contains only the first elements of the nested list.
The nested list L, it's look like:

```
L =[ [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]] ]

for l in L:
 for t in l:
  R.append(t[0])
print 'R=', R
```

The Output is `R= [0, 3, 6, 0, 3, 6, 0, 3, 6]` but I want to get a separated result like:

```
R= [[0, 3, 6], [0, 3, 6], [0, 3, 6]]
```

I've also tried through a list comprehension like `[[R.append(t[0]) for t in l] for l in L]` but this gives `[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your solution returned `[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]` because the method `append` returns the value `None`. Replacing it by `t[0]` should do the trick.

What you're looking for is:

```
R = [[t[0] for t in l] for l in L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
>>> L = [ [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]] ]
>>> R = [ [x[0] for x in sl ] for sl in L ]
>>> print R
[[0, 3, 6], [0, 3, 6], [0, 3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy array with transpose function aswell.

```
import numpy as np
L = [ [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]] ]
Lnumpy = np.array(L)
Ltransposed = Lnumpy.transpose(0, 2, 1) # Order of axis
```

Output is now

```
[[[0 3 6]
  [1 4 7]
  [2 5 8]]

 [[0 3 6]
  [1 4 7]
  [2 5 8]]

 [[0 3 6]
  [1 4 7]
  [2 5 8]]]
```

Now you don't need every first member of member, but just the first member.

`print(Ltransposed[0][0])` now gives you `[0, 3, 6]`
Then

```
for i in ltr:
    print(ltr[0][0])
```

Outputs

```
[0 3 6]
[0 3 6]
[0 3 6]
```

Just for detail, there is also possibility of using zip...(here for Python 3...)

```
print(list(zip(*Ltransposed))[0])
```

Gives you the same. If you need list, convert it back... `list()`...

Answer (score 0):

```
L =[ [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]] ]
R=[]
for l in L:
 temp=[]
 for t in l:
  temp.append(t[0])
 R.append(temp)
print 'R=', R
```

output:

```
R= [[0, 3, 6], [0, 3, 6], [0, 3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the output to be a nested list. You can nest them "by hand" like this :

```
L =[ [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]] ]
R = []
for l in L:
    R2 = []
    for t in l:
        r2.append(t[0])
    R.append(R2)
print 'R=', R
```